# EF 5 Re-Use entity configuration

Tags: entity-framework-5

I'm trying to re-use some of the model configurations on several entities that implements a interface.

Check this code:

```
public static void ConfigureAsAuditable<T>(this EntityTypeConfiguration<T> thisRef)
            where T : class, IAuditable
        {
            thisRef.Property(x => x.CreatedOn)
                .HasColumnName("utctimestamp")
                .IsRequired();

            thisRef.Property(x => x.LastUpdate)
                .HasColumnName("utclastchanged")
                .IsRequired();
        } // ConfigureAsAuditable
```

as you can see I'm trying to call the extension method "ConfigureAsAuditable" on my onmodelcreating method like this:

```
EntityTypeConfiguration<Account> conf = null;

    conf = modelBuilder.Entity<Account>();
    conf.ToTable("dbo.taccount");

    conf.ConfigureAsAuditable();
```

When debugging i get this exception:

> The property 'CreatedOn' is not a declared property on type
>   'Account'. Verify that the property has not been explicitly excluded
>   from the model by using the Ignore method or NotMappedAttribute data
>   annotation. Make sure that it is a valid primitive property.

Thanks in advance :) 
PD:
I'm using EF 5-rc, VS 2011 and .NET Framework 4.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a better approach would be to implement your own derived version of EntityTypeConfiguration.  For example:

```
    public class MyAuditableConfigurationEntityType<T> : EntityTypeConfiguration<T> 
where T : class, IAuditable{
public bool IsAuditable{get;set;}
}
```

Then, when building your model, use that new type:

```
var accountConfiguration = new MyAuditableConfigurationEntityType<Account>();
accountConfiguration.IsAuditable = true; // or whatever you need to set
accountConfiguration.(HasKey/Ignore/ToTable/Whatever)
modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(accountConfiguration);
```